# Automatically run functions in a specific order

Tags: c#

I want to know if there is a way to run all my functions in f.e. the "functions-Class" by putting a certain line in my main method. the idea behind this is, to save some pace and time, writing out every single function and making a terribly long main method.

I'm thinking of sth. like(just to demonstrate what I'm looking for):

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Functions
    {
        public void Function1()
        {
            do.Something();
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunAllFunctionsInFunctionsInAlphabeticalOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is nothing built in... it could be built easily with reflection (but be careful to exclude `Main` to avoid infinite recursion!).

Comment: Are you saying you'd have `Function1`, `Function2`, and `Function3`, and you want to call them without explicitly doing `Functions.Function1()`? That's what reflection is for. However, unless you have hundreds of methods, you're better off just explicitly calling them. And if you have hundreds of methods, you should probably rethink your entire approach.

Comment: Learn OOP instead of asking how to order your functions

Comment: You want to use C# to run your entire app using sequential execution of simple functions? Bad idea. Try using OOP.

Answer (score 2):

Despite all the comments about proper OOP in this case (which, I think, are valid), here is a little reflection-based example:

```
class F
{
    public void F1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello F1");
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f = new F();

        foreach (var method in 
          // get the Type object, that will allow you to browse methods,
          // properties etc. It's the main entry point for reflection
          f.GetType()
             // GetMethods allows you to get MethodInfo objects
             // You may choose which methods do you want -
             // private, public, static, etc. We use proper BindingFlags for that
            .GetMethods(

              // this flags says, that we don't want methods from "object" type,
              // only the ones that are declared here
              BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly

              // we want instance methods (use "Static" otherwise)
            | BindingFlags.Instance

              // only public methods (add "NonPublic" to get also private methods)
            | BindingFlags.Public)

         // lastly, order them by name
         .OrderBy(x => x.Name))
        {
            //invoke the method on object "f", with no parameters (empty array)
            method.Invoke(f, new object[] { });
        }
    }
}
```

This will, effectively, get all public instance method from type `F`, order them by name, and execute with no parameters.

In this particular case, it will display:

> Hello F1

But in general running "all methods", and, even worse, depend on their alphabetical order, is to be strongly discouraged.

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Ok, I got no idea what you are doing here, as I don't know anything about this BindingFlags system, how does that work? What exactly are you doing here?

Comment: I will split the code in lines and comment it to help, but I also recommend https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot again!

Comment: You're welcome! If you think that this answers your question, feel free to mark my post as an answer (the tick sign below the votes).

Answer (score -2):

Use the Func method

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Func<string, string>> methods = new List<Func< string, string>>(){
                methodA, methodB, methodC, methodD
            };

            foreach (Func<string,string> method in methods)
            {
                string result = method("a");

            }


        }
        static string methodA(string a)
        {
            return a;
        }
        static string methodB(string b)
        {
            return b;
        }
        static string methodC(string c)
        {
            return c;
        }
        static string methodD(string d)
        {
            return d;
        }
```

Comment: Asker is looking for a dynamic solution

Comment: Where does the OP ask for a dynamic solution?  Again you are making bad assumptions.

Comment: When he says "save some pace and time, writing out every single function and making a terribly long main method"

Comment: My interpretation is OP wants is to reduce lines of code.  Having an array does that.  OP says "A" (one line) : "putting a certain line in my main method".

Comment: You've not really done that. There's still a list of methods. And now you've got the extra code around it. Anyway, that's my opinion, and wlthats why the votes have been cast. I don't expect you to listen to my opinion, I'm just leaving it here more for others than for you.